# How to Add an Intercept Module in C# MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

In a sample site , I am developing, I wish to have a mobile intercept module.
As soon as the site is browsed from mobile device, i wish it to be redirected to a defferent web application hosted in the same server.
In ASP.Net I know we do it via the httphandlers but how to achieve the same in ASP.Net MVC3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See there couple of ways to do so :(Given in an order by preference of mine)

1. There is a add on reference module by Scott hanselman with which used u can just add as described on [Here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek10NewMobileViewEnginesForASPNETMVC3SpeccompatibleWithASPNETMVC4.aspx) You can use same functionality codes with different view engines. This is a solution if you have the same set of functionalities , and just the views are different to be shown. As a matter of fact you can upgrade to ASP.NET MVC 4 if this is the scenario. Asp.NET MVC 4 contains an inbuilt extension for this. Check out [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852592.aspx) for the same
2. Other way to go is if you have completely different functionalities and it needs to be redirected then you can easily use [51degrees Mobile browser database](http://51degrees.mobi) to do so and check the requesting User agent and redirect it. Now i hope the code isn't expected for this ?

Comment: See I have a different mobile website altogether in a different domain, and all I need to do is if user agent is of mobile, I need to redirect the request to the mobile website. That's why the intercept is required

Comment: Then u need to go for the 2nd way out ... ! And i guess its specified in the answer itself ? Do you need help with the code ?? You can easily find it on google !

Comment: I know how to detect useragents and all, is there a simple approach available, where in I just add a module in somewhere to determine my redirection logic? I dont wish to use any third party dependency

Comment: @AnkushRoy - Dude see u need to check whether the requesting user agent is a Mobile based browser or not. In todays date there are n browsers on Mobile platforms , and if you go wrong then the desktop site will be shown. So you need to use some Mobile user agent database. If not third party u need to create the same. In case u found a better and optimized approach then please do update the answer out here. It will be a good learning for me too.

Comment: @AnkushRoy - brother , ultimately hw did u do it ??

Comment: httphandlers do work in MVC as well, so i just added a new handler ; got the useragent and coded for it ... sorry was out for a year

Comment: @AnkushRoy - Welcome back, But still the question stands is How did you manage to Differentiate User - Agents , Did you create your own database ??